# Weird behaviour with drawables color in Android 4.0 or above

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a strange problem with android resources. I have app created on Android 2.2 `(android:minSdkVersion="8")`. The application works fine.

When I installed app on for example Android 4.0, the application works fine, however at first run some resources are changed.

**For example**, I have drawable color named primary_color which refers to `#FFFFFF` html color. After installation, the system renders black color instead of white. In some cases `@android:color/white` renders black color.

Force closing app and restart app solving this problem.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: does it behave the same on device and emulator?

Comment: i dont use emulator. I tested on few device like samsung galaxy tab 2 , lg l7, asus eee pad and so on.

Comment: try cleaning your project (Project -> Clean)

Comment: i install application from APK file. On android 2.2 or 2.3 works fine, when i install on android 4.0 or 4.1 this weird problem exist ( restarting app load property all drawable)

Comment: **Any idea?** Project clean does not help beccause i installing app from APK file , not from Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in Android versions 4.0 to 4.1.3, I have been testing a similar problem with drawables turning to black only on devices with these versions, it is not present in devices with android version > 4.2.

I'm sure you noticed in your own research but it does not seem to be documented properly and there is no official solution but I can provide a few workarounds:

1) Turn off hardware acceleration, I used a different solution for my problem but this has been known to resolve some issues with images in the above mentioned Android versions. If you want hardware acceleration on for your application you can disable it for the problem activity by adding this to the activity declaration in your manifest.

```
<activity
 android:name="activityName"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
```

2) For a solution specific to your example try setting the color to `@android:color/transparent`, this resolved my issue where I needed a background drawable to remain white.

3) Refer here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34619 to see a similar, documented bug and some of those solutions may work for your issue as well.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I came across the exact same problem!
I had  this on colors.xml

```
 <resources>
    <color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
 </resources>
```

And on styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

The problem was that when using fragment(which contains a ListView) inside an activity the ListView shows white color as background(which is what I need) at first run but at second run the ListView background was black. The problem only existed on Android 4.0(I did not test on 4.1) but worked fine on Android 4.3, 4.4, 5 etc.

Turns out only white color had the problem, when colors other than white was used there was no black background issue!

So as I wanted a white background and I did not want to have overdraw of having multiple background so setting white as the windowBackground on styles.xml was important but at the same time it causes black background issues!

So as solution, I created another color which is not completely white but its white

```
<resources>
    <color name="fakewhite">#fffefefe</color>
</resources>
```

And on styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/fakewhite</item>
</style>
```

Hence, in short color #ffffffff gets converted to #00000000 for Views like ListView and I also notice this behaviour on ScrollView.
This may not be a perfect solution but it worked for me!